# JVM Restartability in Weblogic

Tags: asynchronous, jvm, weblogic, batch-processing

I have a weblogic server running in clustered mode with one admin server(A) and 3 managed servers(M1,M2,M3). A and M1 reside on the same machine. In the weblogic, I am running a multi-tiered J2EE application, where an asynchronous batch process is invoked from the UI. We noticed, that when the M1 is killed (due to server load etc) - and restarted, the batch process that was invoked continues to run. My assumption would have been that the batch process also starts within the same JVM as M1. I have checked all the java processes running on the box, but none of them point to executing this batch in a separate JVM.

Appreciate your help !

Contrib

Comment: If you kill the server can you still see the java process running? Are the servers in your cluster set to Automatic Service Migration?

Comment: hello, yes, the java process is still running. The process logs into another location, and the log shows that the process runs without a problem. The servers have Migratable target set to true. Am I correct to say that the cluster automatically migrates the execution (to put it simply) into another server in the cluster. Can you please help me find - how do I get to find which JVM is current executing the process? (A heap dump perhaps?)